# CS1003 Syntax error, 'when' expected

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Its been quite some time that I read about Exception filters in C# 6.0

I was to trying to use it in action. But not sure why I am getting the below error.

> CS1003    Syntax error, 'when' expected   C_6.0

This is how my snippet looks like

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace C_6._0
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int val = 1;
        try
        {
            WriteLine("Enter value :");
            val = int.Parse(ReadLine());

        }
        catch (Exception ex) if (val == 0)
        {
            WriteLine("Input Invalid");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        ReadLine();
    }
 }}
```

I checked the version of C#, its 6.0 in my visual studio by

Properties -> Build -> Advanced Build Settings

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change `if (val == 0)` to `when (val == 0)`?

Comment: @mjwills, it builds but the links that I was referring shows to use if

Comment: @mjwills http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/exception-filter-in-C-Sharp-6-0/

Comment: Well, that page is wrong.

Comment: In early development of C# 6, it was `if` but they eventually changed it to `when`.

Comment: @Kgn-web it's better to read the *docs* than articles on various sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many links online do show that the `if` should be correct but it is not true anymore. Syntax of the filtered exception is with `when` and not `if`:

```
try
{
    // Code here
}
catch (Exception ex) when (val == 0)
{
    WriteLine("Input Invalid");
}
```

See here on [**Official** MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#exception-filters)

---

The article you commented is out of date. As mentioned by mjwills the reason is that in previous versions of the Visual Studio 2015 CTP, the if keyword was used instead of when.

Comment: But all this links says about using if http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/exception-filter-in-C-Sharp-6-0/

Comment: Cool.. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, it would be really great if you could please add just line to your post **Note: In previous versions of the Visual Studio 2015 CTP, the if keyword was used instead of when.**

Answer (score 2):

Exception filtering used to use `if` (in CTP) but now uses `when`.

```
catch (Exception ex) when (val == 0)
```

[This blog entry](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/04/09/c.net-little-wonders-exception-filtering-in-c-6.aspx) states:

> Note: In previous versions of the Visual Studio 2015 CTP, the if
>   keyword was used instead of when.

Answer (score 0):

Use `when` instead of `if`

```
catch (Exception ex) when (val == 0)
```